# DynamDB save autogenerated value at two fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following java model:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Transaction")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Transaction {
    private String name; 

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    private Long createdAt;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "nameCreatedAt")
    public String getNameCreatedAt() {
        return String.join("_", name, String.valueOf(createdAt));
    }
   
    public void setNameCreatedAt(final String nameCreatedAt) {
        // Noop.
    }
}
```

I need to save the createdAt value at two places. But when saving the createdAt value will be null and doesn't gets populated at the second field, nameCreatedAt but saves at the first field. What is the right approach for saving the same autogenerated value at two fields?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that the annotations are processed internally by the mapper, on save, but the generated values are available in memory and not on the model itself.

As far as I can tell from the DynamoDBMapper code on GitHub there are no easy ways to hook into the mapper code to make changes to the model but instead of using the `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp` annotation you could make a small change on your model to add a helper method to generate the timestamp and update both fields yourself, right before you call save.

```
public class Transaction {
  private String name; 
  
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "createdAt")
  private Long createdAt;

  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "nameCreatedAt")
  private String nameCreatedAt;
  
  // remember to call this before you save
  public void generateTimestamp() {
    createdAt = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    nameCreatedAt = String.join("_", name, String.valueOf(createdAt));
  }

}
```

It's not as elegant as using annotations because you will have to ensure to call the method before you save but it will work.